# Why is asteroid 2001VB still on the risk list?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Why is asteroid 2001VB still on the risk list and how likely is it to impact the Earth this year? Moreover, on July 23, 2023 it will be several kilometers from us according to NASA's orbit view, how can it impact?

Comment: "Several kilometers" is **very close**. Did you mean a larger number such a several thousand kilometers?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [2001 VB - when will it be reacquired?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/44497/2001-vb-when-will-it-be-reacquired)?

Comment: yes, I meant that.
But if the probability that it impacts was for a “keyhole” in the Venus flyby in 2002, at 0.1 AU. According to their calculations it passed at a distance of 0.02 AU, the impact should be almost certain or not?

Comment: 1AU = 150 million kilometers = distance Sun-Earth. Thus 0.02 AU = 3 million kilometers or of the order of 300 Earth diameter or 10 distances moon-earth

Comment: this doesn't answer my question…

Comment: See https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/sentry/intro.html for info on how impact risk is determined, including the new algorithm which was introduced in 2021.

Comment: This object isn't on the risk list.

Comment: @JamesK it looks like its at the top of this list: https://neo.ssa.esa.int/risk-list

Comment: that's right, this is number one on the list. So is the probability of impact up to date or is it based on the 2001 calculations?
And considering that it passed within 0.1 AU of Venus in 2002, has the probability changed?

Comment: See https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/sentry/details.html#?des=2001%20VB

Comment: which is the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Any prediction for 2001 VB depends on a small set of observations spanning 7 days in November 2001.
JPL [SBDB](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/tools/sbdb_lookup.html#/?sstr=2001%20VB) estimates its orbital period as 1351±124 days, uncertain by 9%.
It may be useful to think of its probable position as a cloud instead of a point.
If I read the vector tables from JPL [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) correctly,
that cloud has grown from 30 by 3×10<sup>5</sup> km when it was observed,
to 10<sup>5</sup> by 3×10<sup>6</sup> km 4 months later when it was supposed to have encountered Venus,
to 3×10<sup>6</sup> by 6×10<sup>8</sup> km now.

[ESA's risk list](https://web.archive.org/web/20230706183152/https://neo.ssa.esa.int/risk-list) has different rules for inclusion than [JPL Sentry](https://cneos.jpl.nasa.gov/sentry/) does, but they computed similar orbital parameters and uncertainties from the same set of observations.
On the "Orbit Properties" tab [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20230330235645/https://neo.ssa.esa.int/search-for-asteroids?sum=1&des=2001VB), their estimate for [mean anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) at MJD 60000 (2023-02-25) has a ±168° error bar.
In other words, for all we know, 2001 VB could now be almost anywhere along its orbit.

All bets are off. Only a new observation can change this, and unfortunately none is available.

Answer (score 0):

It's not on JPL but for some reason it's on ESA. Though for the ESA it states its next approach isn't until 2048. It at one point had a chance, but the chance only ever got to 1 in 200 million. It was scratched off the sentry risk list in early 2021, which means it cites no danger to earth. And both observation sites pin the asteroid either ~2.7 or ~3.2 au away from earth as of July 22nd 2023.

Comment: Given the extremely wide range of possible positions *now*, I'm not sure how ESA can establish even a year for the next approach. Sounds like guesswork to me.